# Change color of button based on bound item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this xaml for a button that is bound to a class.  I've added another property to the class and want the background color of the button to be yellow if the value of the property is greater than zero.

```
<local:TileView x:Key="Button_Available_View">
  <local:TileView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Button 
          Command="command:Command_Button_AvailableTags.Command"   
          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}"
          Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
          Tag="{Binding Path=Name}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Padding="3,1,3,1"
          Margin="0"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
          />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </local:TileView.ItemTemplate>
</local:TileView>
```

How would I modify this?

Comment: Bind the color to the property but then you need a converter to return a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've come up with:

```
Background="{Binding Path=BackColor}"
```

And then in the code behind binding class:

```
public Brush BackColor
{
    get
    {
        if (SimilarHits > 0) return Brushes.Yellow;
        return Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
    }
}
```

I don't understand WPF, it seems you have to write twenty lines to say `"hello world"`.

Marking this the answer - least amount of code to get the result desired.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://anders.janmyr.com/2007/09/combining-datatriggers-and-property.html) should give you some good examples to work off of.  The essence of it is that you need to use a style trigger to determine which color your background should be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the Foreground property of the button to the property of the view model. Then you can use a converter to convert the value to color.

The converter would look like this:

```
public class TextToColorConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((int)value) > 0)
                return Brushes.Yellow; 
            else
                // for default value 
                return Brushes.Blue; 
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // no need to implement it 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Edited: Updated the xaml to bind the background instead of the Foreground 
The xaml would be:

```
    <Button
   Background="{Binding Path=Property, Converter={StaticResource textToColorConverter}}"                 Command="command:Command_Button_AvailableTags.Command"              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}"           Content="{Binding Path=Name}"           Tag="{Binding Path=Name}"            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"           Padding="3,1,3,1"           Margin="0"           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"            />
```

Of course, you have to add the converter as a static resource to the page.

Comment: Actually needs to bind background not foreground

Comment: I down voted your answer by accident.  If you will change your answer I can remove the down vote.

Comment: well you can bind to Background then. I will edit that in the answer so you can remove the down vote :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I get the error: `'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' value cannot be assigned to property 'Background' of object 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'. Specified cast is not valid.` I've tried `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media` for the `Brushes` object, and also tried `"Yellow"` and `"Blue"`, but none work.

Comment: You should use System.Windows.Media.Brushes. Are you writting a WPF app and which version are you targetting? It works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create either an `IValueConverter` on your binding that converts the value of the property to a color, or use a `DataTrigger` in the style of your item that sets the color based on value?